# [QuickSort]Recursion Problems

Tags: c, algorithm

When I was running my QuickSort code, and input the numbers.
There was no output at all.
I do not know the problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quickSort(int *pA, int left, int right) {
    int i, j, t, temp;
    temp = pA[left];
    i = left;
    j = right;
    while (i != j) {
        while (i < j && pA[j] >= temp)
            j--;
        while (i < j && pA[i] <= temp)
            i++;
        if (i < j) {
             t = pA[i];
             pA[i] = pA[j];
             pA[j] = t;
        }
    }
     pA[left] = pA[i];
     pA[i] = temp;
     quickSort(pA, left, i - 1);
     quickSort(pA, i + 1, right);
}

int main() {
    int i, n, a[100];
    printf("please input the total of numbers:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("number %d is:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    quickSort(&a, 0, n - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Next was the code running picture:
[image]

Comment: so you call `quicksort()` inside `quicksort()`? how do you expect this loop to end?

Comment: Click on the grey field to the left of `while(i!=j)` Red dot will appear; it is called "break point". Press F5 to run your code. Once the line with the red dot is reached, the program will pause, and wait for your actions. Press F10 to step to the next line. If the cursor is on a function call, press F11 to step into it. To learn more tricks of this sort, search "VS debugging" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: You need a stop condition. If the size of the slice is less than 2, then `quickSort` should return without making any new calls to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a test in your recursive `quickSort` for it to stop recursing! For example a segment of just 1 entry is obviously sorted.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quickSort(int *pA, int left, int right) {
    int i, j, t, temp;
    if (right - left < 1)
        return;
    temp = pA[left];
    i = left;
    j = right;
    while (i != j) {
        while (i < j && pA[j] >= temp)
            j--;
        while (i < j && pA[i] <= temp)
            i++;
        if (i < j) {
             t = pA[i];
             pA[i] = pA[j];
             pA[j] = t;
        }
    }
     pA[left] = pA[i];
     pA[i] = temp;
     quickSort(pA, left, i - 1);
     quickSort(pA, i + 1, right);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, n, a[100];
    printf("please input the total of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("number %d is: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    quickSort(a, 0, n - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```